# cURL request into Swift vs Python

Tags: python, swift, curl, request, http-headers

I am trying to implement a cURL request into Swift App, however, the server is not accepting my request for some reason.

cURL Request:

```
curl 'https://test.com' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Origin: https://yyy.com' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: https://zzz.com' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  --data-binary '{"method":"NewUser","params":{"Username":"James","Password":"secret"}}' \
  --compressed
```

I have managed to do this in Python and it worked:

```
import requests

url = "https://test.com"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict
headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
headers["Accept"] = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
headers["cache-control"] = "no-cache"
headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers["Origin"] = "https://yyy.com"
headers["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "same-origin"
headers["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "cors"
headers["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "empty"
headers["Referer"] = "https://zzz"
headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"

data = '{"method":"NewUser","params":{"Username":"James","Password":"Secret"}}'

raw_response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

What I am trying to do in Swift is:

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://test.com")!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("keep-alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
        request.addValue("application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "cache-control")
        request.addValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")
        request.addValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        request.addValue("https://yyy.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
        request.addValue("same-origin", forHTTPHeaderField: "Sec-Fetch-Site")
        request.addValue("cors", forHTTPHeaderField: "Sec-Fetch-Mode")
        request.addValue("empty", forHTTPHeaderField: "Sec-Fetch-Dest")
        request.addValue("https://zzz.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
        request.addValue("en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
        
        let json: [String: Any] = ["method": "NewUser","params": ["Username":"James", "Password":"Secret"]]
        
        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
        
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
        
        task.resume()
```

Any idea what is the difference between Python/Swift code that it's not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to know what is the error your server returns back ?

Comment: Hey @ShawnFrank, I am getting boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics.

Comment: @ShawnFrank ok this boringssl is solved, however, the server still not accepting the request format. Unfortunately, can't post the error but it would not tell you much anyway. How can I see the full request that is sent to the server? Can I print it somehow?

Comment: Probably using pastebin or a gist and you can add the link to your question as someone might be able to help with the added info.

Comment: Your request seems correct. Is `error` nil? And `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`? There might be a info there on why it fails...

Comment: Wait a moment, it seems like your configured `request` is not being used. You use `URLSession.shared.dataTask withURL` when you should probably use `dataTask(with request:` and pass the request as the parameter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask - for now it seems you just pass the url, not the configured request to the URLSession.

Comment: @ShawnFrank OMG I am an idiot! :D Of course. Working now! Thanks a lot.